# How to set a normal height for uk-body in uk-modal?

Tags: html, css, angular, uikit

I'm trying to make a functional modal window using uiKit. This is a modal:[image]

This is its body:[image]

Here is a code I wrote for this modal:

```
<div id="adjust-export-modal" uk-modal>
  <div class="uk-modal-dialog" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
      <button
        class="uk-modal-close-default"
        type="button"
        uk-close
        #close
      ></button>
      <div class="uk-modal-header">
        <h2 class="uk-modal-title">Adjust exported report</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="uk-modal-body" style="/*width: 100%; height: 100%;*/ padding: 0">
        <app-report-grid
          [companyId]="companyId"
        ></app-report-grid>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`<app-report-grid>` is not functional at the screenshots, but when it is, it takes all the blue space of uk-modal-body and takes away all the bottom margin.

What should I do to make uk-modal-body stay inside the modal edges? Or there is a different possible option: what should I do to make uk-modal-body expand exact modal and make it scrollable, without taking away the bottom margin?

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding a specific height and width to **uk-modal-dialog**

```
.uk-modal{
    display:block;
}

.uk-modal-dialog {
    width: 60vw;
    min-width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

This will make your inside modal context understand that 100% is 100% of its actual size, because sometimes when everthing is set to 100% it just render default values.
Also add **display:block** to modal if it's not that way.

If that doesn't work, try by setting size to **.uk-modal-body** and then set **.uk-modal-dialog**'s height to **height: fit-content**. This will auto-adjust dialog height to its content size.

```
.uk-modal-dialog{
    height: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
    width: 600px;
    max-width: 600px;
}

.uk-modal-dialog {
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I actually needed to explore vh in css to solve the exact issue, which I faced. Speaking about this problem, it was about that I used `height: 100%` for modal-body, but I did not leave out that modal-header is also a part of modal. That's why modal-body was too big